# Python: Tkinter Keypress Event Trigger once: Hold vs. Pressed

Tags: python, events, triggers, tkinter, keypress

What do I have to do so that the function that I bind with the `<KeyPress>` event only triggers once, even when I hold the key?

Answer (score 0):

There may be nothing you can do. It could very well be that the keyboard itself is sending multiple events (ie: it's a hardware problem that can't be solved with software).

These events are probably coming very close together -- maybe every 100ms or so. You can use that knowledge to affect how you process events. For example, you can only do something special on a key release if it was at least 200ms after the last press.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I hoped tkinter hat something like KeyPressed or KeyPressing Event. I made a kind-off workaround for this problem.

```css
from tkinter import*

m='<KeyPress>'
n='<KeyRelease>'

global kp
kp=0

def press(event):
    global kp

    if (kp!=event.keysym):
        print(event.keysym)
        kp=event.keysym



def release(event):
    global kp

    print(event.keysym)
    kp=0

root.bind(m,press)
root.bind(n,release)
```